Directed Graph Edit Distance Computation Issue Using AStar Algorithm in Graph-Matching-Toolkit
I am comparing pairs of identical directed graphs represented in GXL format using the Graph-Matching-Toolkit(https://github.com/dzambon/graph-matching-toolkit). Since the graphs are identical, I expect the Graph Edit Distance (GED) to be 0.
Example Graph:
<gxl>
  <graph id="418" edgeids="false" edgemode="directed">
    <node id="0" />
    <node id="1" />
    <node id="2" />
    <node id="3" />
    <node id="4" />
    <node id="5" />
    <node id="6" />
    <node id="7" />
    <node id="8" />
    <node id="9" />
    <edge from="0" to="1" />
    <edge from="0" to="3" />
    <edge from="0" to="5" />
    <edge from="0" to="9" />
    <edge from="1" to="2" />
    <edge from="2" to="7" />
    <edge from="3" to="4" />
    <edge from="4" to="7" />
    <edge from="6" to="8" />
    <edge from="6" to="7" />
  </graph>
</gxl>


Attribute File:
###     :::::::::::::::::::::: IMPORTANT INFORMATION :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::    #
#
#   consult the following website (and the corresponding paper) for
#   more detailed information about the individual parameters and
#   their meanings:
#
#   http://www.fhnw.ch/wirtschaft/iwi/gmt
#
###     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::    #



#########################################################################################
#   source and target graph set, pathes to the graph and result folder      #
#########################################################################################
source=./data/BugTest/small.xml
target=./data/BugTest/small.xml
path=./data/BugTest/
result=./result/BugTest


#########################################################################################
#   graph matching paradigm (possible choices are: AStar, Beam, Hungarian, VJ)  #
#   if "Beam" is chosen, maximum number of open paths s has to be defined       #
#########################################################################################
matching=AStar
s=
adj=best

#########################################################################################
#   cost for node/edge deletions/insertions (both cost values have to be > 0)   #
#########################################################################################
node=1
edge=1


#########################################################################################
#   number of node attributes and the individual names of these attributes      #
#########################################################################################
numOfNodeAttr=0


#########################################################################################
#   cost function type per individual node attribute                #
#   (possible choices are: squared, absolute, discrete, sed)            #
#   if cost-function=discrete for node attribute i: nodeCostMui and nodeCostNui #
#   (non-negative real values) have to be additionally defined          #
#########################################################################################


#########################################################################################
#   weighting parameters per individual node attribute              #
#   (min=0, max=1.0; default = 1.0)                         #
#########################################################################################



#########################################################################################
#   individual node costs are added (multiplyNodeCosts=0) or            #
#   multiplied (multiplyNodeCosts=1)                        #
#   p-th root is extracted from the combined node cost              #
#########################################################################################
multiplyNodeCosts=0
pNode=1


#########################################################################################
#   edges are directed (=0) or undirected (=1)                  #
#########################################################################################
undirected=0


#########################################################################################
#   number of edge attributes and the individual names of these attributes      #
#########################################################################################
numOfEdgeAttr=0


#########################################################################################
#   cost function type per individual edge attribute                #
#   (possible choices are: squared, absolute, discrete, sed)            #
#   if cost-function=discrete for edge attribute i: nodeCostMui and nodeCostNui #
#   (non-negative real values) have to be additionally defined          #
#########################################################################################



#########################################################################################
#   weighting parameters per individual edge attribute              #
#   (min=0, max=1.0; default = 1.0)                         #
#########################################################################################
edgeAttr0Importance=0

#########################################################################################
#   individual edge costs are added (multiplyEdgeCosts=0) or            #
#   multiplied (multiplyEdgeCosts=1)                        #
#   p-th root is extracted from the combined edge cost              #
#########################################################################################
multiplyEdgeCosts=0
pEdge=1


#########################################################################################
#   alpha weights the node and edge costs:                      #
#   alpha * nodeCost; (1-alpha) * edgeCost
#########################################################################################
alpha=0.5


#########################################################################################
#   logging options on the console                          #
#########################################################################################
outputGraphs=0
outputEditpath=0
outputCostMatrix=0
outputMatching=0


#########################################################################################
#   build similarities from distances or not (possible choices are 0,1,2,3,4)   #
#########################################################################################
simKernel=0


Observed Behavior:
When I compute the GED using the AStar algorithm with the parameter undirected=0, the resulting GED is 10 instead of the expected 0.
Questions:
Data Validation:
Is there a possibility that my directed graph data has an issue that affects the GED computation?
Toolkit Functionality:
Could there be a bug or limitation in how the toolkit handles directed graphs, especially when using the AStar algorithm with undirected=0?
Data Validation:
Verified that both source and target GXL files are identical by performing a file comparison.
Ensured that the GXL files are well-formed and adhere to the correct schema.
Removed edge id attributes from the GXL files to match the format of another graph that worked correctly
